# PHP convert integer to time

Tags: php, datetime, time, converters

How can I convert integer to time in minutes e.g. `5` would give `30mins`. I've tried

```
<?php
     $toMin = 5; 
     echo date('i', ($toMin*60)).'mins';
?>
```

But it only returns `05mins`

Comment: Why would `5` give `30mins`?

Comment: [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) - *"The optional timestamp parameter is an integer Unix timestamp"* the Unix Timestamp is in seconds so you are passing 5 seconds * 60 seconds = 300 seconds = 5 minutes

Comment: I need to convert it into mins since some of returned data are like 7.5, 8.3, 2.2. I used `explode('.', $number)` to separate them first, and now I'm stuck in converting the second array value to minutes.

Comment: @PenAndPapers, what "returned data"? What do those numbers represent? Why did you explode them on `.`? What does it mean to "convert the second array value to minutes"? And, again, _why should an input of `5` give an output of `30mins`_? I honestly don't understand how that conversion is supposed to work. **Edit:** Is `5` really supposed to represent `0.5 hours`? (Wild guess based on your `explode()` comment and the expected result.)

Comment: i assume 7.5 = seven and a half hours .. so  60*0.5 =30

Comment: @Dagon that would make sense if the OP disclosed that

Comment: @Chris for example the input is 7.5 the 7 represents the hour and 5 is the minutes, but in my case the 5 should be converted/equal to 30mins.

Comment: So… does that mean we guessed correctly, @PenAndPapers? `5` really means `0.5 hours`? 80% of getting a good answer is asking a good question. Please read [ask]. We shouldn't have to work this hard just to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: solved Thanks @Dagon :)

Comment: I also think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your real question is how to convert an input like `7.5` (representing hours) to some other format, maybe `7:30` or `7h30m` or even `450 minutes`. You _think_ the answer is to convert 7.5 to a string, explode it on `.`, deal with the hours, and then you're left with `5` to _somehow_ turn into 30. But that just confuses the question further. In the future, please ask about your _real question_, not what you think the solution is.

Comment: Noted @Chris I'll do next time and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so something like:

```
$time='7.5'; //, 8.3, 2.2. 

$x=explode('.',$time);

$min=60*($x[1]/10);

echo $x[0] .'hours and '.$min.'mins';
```